# Plot shaded area below the line

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to shade the area below the line, but when doing that I am obtaining a shade area above the line even though I indicated below. Do you know what is the problem when shading the area?

```
set style fill patter 2 border
set style data lines
plot "data2.dat" using 1:3:4:5 with yerrorlines ls 1 linecolor rgb "blue",\
      ""         using 1:2 with filledcurves below linecolor rgb "red"
```

The result is in the opposite direction:
[image]

My data is:

```
X                Y1            Y2         C.Interval(-)  C.Interval(+)     
0.1            0.1111        0.1111       0.110950699    0.111166503
0.2            0.2500        0.2498       0.249474612    0.250095218      
0.4            0.6667        0.6675       0.666310581    0.668667648
0.6            1.4993        1.4962       1.491809644    1.500612543   
0.8            4.0000        4.0069       3.982266522    4.031590962
```

How could I shade the area below?

Thank you

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I think that I need to include the parameter x1 after below to indicate that the shaded area has to be below the line.

```
gnuplot> plot "data2.dat" using 1:3:4:5 with yerrorlines ls 1 linecolor rgb "blue",\
""         using 1:2 with filledcurves below x1 linecolor rgb "red"
```

[image]

Comment: You can (actually should) accept your own solution indicating that the problem is solved.